# Ruby can't find installed gems

Tags: rubygems

I'm a bit at the end of my wits here.  I'm on OSX10.6 and my gems are all screwed up.  One of the gems I'm trying to use is Hashie.  I've looked around on the internet and several people seem to be having similar problems but I none of their solutions seem to work in my case.  Thanks for looking.

All my ruby scripts / gems are installed in /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02:

```
Komputor:~$ which ruby gem irb rails
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/irb
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/rails
```

And the example gem, hashie (and many others) are installed:

```
Komputor:~ $ gem list -l | wc -l
      67
Komputor:~ $ gem list | grep hashie
hashie (0.4.0)
Komputor:gems $ cd /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems
Komputor:gems $ ls | grep hashie
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  admin   442 Nov 24 17:13 hashie-0.4.0
```

Yet when I try to access them from irb or a script, it all fails:

```
Komputor:~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'hashie'
LoadError: no such file to load -- hashie
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>
```

Some environment variables:
Gem env:

```
Komputor:gems $ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-darwin10.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/<snip>/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

$PATH:

```
Komputor:gems $ echo $PATH
/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin:/Applications/android-sdk-1.5/tools:/usr/brlcad/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.0.67-osx10.5-x86_64/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin:/sw/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

I'll be happy to post up the output of any commands for debugging.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Don't you have to "require 'rubygems'" before you can "require 'hashie'"?

Comment: Okay, this gets me halfway there. 

I notice that rails has this in the boot.rb file.  A file in my lib folder requires hashie also, and I added require 'rubygems' above the require 'hashie' line, and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Adam Vandenberg points out, before loading a gem you need to `require "rubygems"`

Some frameworks may load this for you, and you can set it to autoload in your `.irbrc` if you like

Comment: I know this is old, but since I came here by google: ruby 1.8 does need `require 'rubygems'`. Starting with ruby 1.9 it doesn't.